# unit testing for flutter firebase storage using mockito not working

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, firebase-storage

I am trying to do testing for my android app using unit testing for the Firebase Storage.

Below is the unit test code.

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:kopimate/services/firebase_storage_service.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';

class MockStorage extends Mock implements Storage {}
void main() {
  
  final MockStorage mockStorage = MockStorage();
  final Storage storage = Storage(storage: mockStorage);

  setUp(() {});
  tearDown(() {});

  test('download URL using non-existing imgName', () async {
    when(mockStorage.downloadURL('1'))
      .thenAnswer((realInvocation) => 'e' as Future<String>);

    expect(await storage.downloadURL('1'), 'error');
  });
}
```

Below is the code for my Storage.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart' as firebase_storage;

class Storage {
  final firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage storage =
      firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance;

  Storage({storage});

  Future<String> downloadURL(String imageName) async {
  try {
    String downloadURL =
        await storage.ref('shops/$imageName.jpg').getDownloadURL();
    return downloadURL;
  } on FirebaseException {
    return 'error';
  } catch (e) {
    rethrow;
  }
 } 
}
```

When I run the test, it keeps showing that the test did not record any output in the test results terminal of vscode.